# How to put this element to first place using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make id="a" element div to be the first div in the div.b element.

Here is the code:

```
<div class='b'>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div id="a">I want to put this div to be the first div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want this div element to be inserted through jQuery after the page loads or the page is already in the html before the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll also need to remove the #a element after/before prepending or you'll have duplicates. I would suggest:

```
var aCopy = $('#a').clone();
$('#a').remove();
$('#b').prepend(aCopy);
```

Comment: This isn't necessary when there is only a single instance of #b (as would be since # looks up an id which should be unique), however if there are more one should use this approach or end up with duplicates, see http://api.jquery.com/prepend/, still there is no need to clone if one can first prepend  and then remove, but it isn't always possible

Comment: Actually you need **only one line of code** like in the other answer in this thread: `$('#b').prepend($('#a'));` You have no need to clone and remove the node.

Comment: I concur with @Konstantin. Removal isn't necessary; `prepend` and `append` handle that for you.

Answer (score 8):

Use `prepend`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)</sup>*:

```
$('#b').prepend($('#a'));
```

Or, if it's more convenient, you can use `prependTo`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)</sup>*:

```
$('#a').prependTo($('#b'));
```

Comment: what if I want to make it just the opposite way, ie, I want to make it to exacty the last div

Comment: `append` and `appendTo` work the same way, except they will move the element to last child position, instead of the first.

Comment: @user1063434... you will use `append` or `appendTo`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
var prep=$('#a');
$('#b').prepend(prep);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert through jQuery then there is a function prepend which inserts the element as the first element.

YOu can check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) for more information.

Append will do just the opposite to prepend.